# How can I fill a gap between my new threshold and the hardwood flooring?

Tags: doors

The old exterior front door threshold 1 3/4 inch. The new exterior door threshold is 1 1/2. I would like to find a good looking way and nice looking way to fill the gap between the threshold and the beautiful flooring.

Comment: what kind of flooring? do you have any pieces of it? perhaps in a garage or attic?

Comment: It's not apparent what those dimensions represent. Please post a clear photo of the scenario.

Comment: So it's a quarter inch gap? Would a small piece of moulding (square, quarter round, etc) do it?